# Losing internet while connecting second Ethernet cable to access network share

Tags: linux, networking, internet, ethernet, network-shares

I have a machine that runs CentOS 7, right now I am struggling with a network issue that I think is fairly easy to solve. I have an network share (NFS) that I can connect to and mount - this involves connecting a second Ethernet cable to my machine.

The problem I have now is that I am losing the internet connection when I connect the second ethernet cable (the network share). If I only have the Ethernet cable to the network share inserted, the network share can be accessed. If I have both cables connected the network share can be accessed but internet goes down.

In the "Wired settings" for the internet connection I am manually setting IPv4 given by my Internet Service Provider such as Address (IP), Netmask and Gateway. The same goes with the network share connection, here I also set Address (IP), Netmask and Gateway.

I've tried to disable/set the gateway to 0.0.0.0 in the "Wired settings" for the network share without any success to getting internet working.

How could I have internet (Ethernet cable 1) and my network share connected (Ethernet cable 2) without sacrificing the internet connection? Worth mentioning is that the motherboard (it's a server) has two Ethernet ports - it also have a second network card with 6 ports, I have tried different ones.

Help to solve this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I get that you want port 1 to have a public ip. Does your nfs nic also have a public or private IP? If your going for public, you have to pay your ISP for another global IP address. If it's private, I would assume you need NAT in-between public and private. Update your answer with topology, and the logical ip addressing you have setup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your routing table and set it so that all data bound for the share are routed to it, and all other packets are routed out to the internet. Also keep in mind that you can only have one gateway.